# Moving object in a game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an image, and I am trying to move around using a function:

```
public void MoveXY(Vector2 target)
{
    Vector2 startPosition = this.pos;
    Vector2 endPosition = target;
    float lerpAmount = 0.05f;
    this.pos = Vector2.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, lerpAmount);
}
```

I'm calling this in a game update loop.

I want to make some variable **bool moving** that tracks if my obj is moving, but I have difficulty imaging how to implement this in the game loop.

I need something like:

```
obj.MoveXY(target1);
```

If the command one is finished:

```
obj.MoveXY(target2);
```

What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: You can use "Coroutines" to achive that, or a simple `Update` method, which is available on every `GameObject`. I also believe there is some kind of a `.MoveTo` method on a `Transform` object, which is the `.position` field of your game object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty you are experiencing is typical for gaming applications. Unlike in regular applications, you cannot simply reflect sequences of actions by statement sequences, as only a tiny fraction of it will ever be executed at each gaming loop update.

You must remember the current state of the game and of each action accross updates. This can become quite complex. A solution to this problem is to use a [Finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) as explained here [Game Programming Patterns / Design Patterns Revisited: State](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html) and here [Gamedevelopment
Finite-State Machines: Theory and Implementation](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/finite-state-machines-theory-and-implementation--gamedev-11867).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple code for object move:

```
pulbic class ObjectMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 targetPos;
    float lerpAmount = 0.05f;
    public bool moving = true;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, targetPos, lerpAmount);

        if(transform.position == target.position)
           moving = false;
    }

    public void MoveXY(Vector2 target)
    {
        targetPos = target;
        moving = true;
    }
}
```

Then in another script, you can check if the object arrives to the target and set a new target:

```
if(obj.moving == false)
   obj.MoveXY(newTarget);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Specify the targets in the inspector
// Make sure you have at least one target, otherwise, you will have an IndexOutOfRange Exception
public Transform[] TargetObjects;
public float MovementSpeed = 1;
private bool objectMoving= false;
private int currentTargetIndex;

public void MoveObjectToTarget(Transform objectToMove, Transform target, float maxDistanceDelta )
{
    objectToMove.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(objectToMove.position, target.position, maxDistanceDelta );
    return (objectToMove.position - target.position).sqrMagnitude < 0.01f;
}

void Update()
{
    if( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.Space ) ) // Toggle whether the object will move to the target
        objectMoving = !objectMoving;

    if( objectMoving )
    {
        if( MoveObjectToTarget( transform, TargetObjects[currentTargetIndex], Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed; ) )
        {
            Debug.Log( "Target reached" ) ;
            currentTargetIndex = (currentTargetIndex + 1) % TargetObjects.Length ;
        }
    }
}
```